# Adding attachments to Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add attachment to google calendar from google drive using Google apis. I tried following code which gets executed properly without any exception or error but attachment is not getting added in calendar event.

```
 private void  addattachment(String eveID, String fileID, string Calid)
     {
         try
         {
            Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event f_event  =   m_CalService.Events.Get(Calid, eveID).Execute();
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File f_File = m_DriveService.Files.Get(fileID).Execute();

            List<EventAttachment> f_ListEventAttach = (List<EventAttachment>)f_event.Attachments;

            if (f_ListEventAttach == null)
                f_ListEventAttach = new List<EventAttachment>();

            f_ListEventAttach.Add(new EventAttachment() 
            { FileUrl = FileUrl,
                MimeType = f_File.MimeType,
                Title = f_File.Name}
                            );
            Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event newEvent = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event();
            newEvent.Attachments = f_ListEventAttach;

            m_CalService.Events.Patch(newEvent, Calid, eveID).SupportsAttachments = true;
            m_CalService.Events.Patch(newEvent, Calid, eveID).Execute();


         }
    }
```

Thank you,
Renuka

Comment: My guess would be that  m_CalService.Events.Patch(newEvent, Calid, eveID).Execute(); does not actually have supportsAttachments set to true. I would first of all switch to Update instead of patch. Then I would save the Update request into a variable, set the supportsAttachments on that variable and then call execute on the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File f_file1 = null;
                f_file1 = m_DriveService.Files.Get("fileID").Execute();
                EventAttachment attach1 = new EventAttachment();
                //attach.FileId = file.Id;
                attach1.Title = f_file1.Name;
                attach1.MimeType = f_file1.MimeType;

                attach1.FileUrl = FileURL;
                List<EventAttachment> listEveAttach1 = new List<EventAttachment>();
                listEveAttach1.Add(attach1);
                f_CalEventObj.Attachments = listEveAttach1;

                m_CalService.Events.Insert(f_CalEventObj, obj_addedCal).SupportsAttachments = true;
                EventsResource.InsertRequest obj_request = m_CalService.Events.Insert(f_CalEventObj, obj_addedCal);
                obj_request.SupportsAttachments = true;
                Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event obj_AddedEvent = obj_request.Execute();
```

Its working properly..